# ViewData.Eval for Collections

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I believe that ViewData.Eval does not work for collection objects.

The following returns null.

```
<%=ViewData.Eval("Names[0].FirstName")%>
<%=ViewData.Eval("Names[1].FirstName")%>
```

My app requires that the model be accessed using Eval and not strongly typed methods like Model.Names[0].FirstName etc.

How can I achieve this?

Version of MVC is 1.0

Thanks.

Comment: You have a strange app requirement for not using strongly typed methods.

Comment: Basically, it is a dynamic form app where the field names come from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I achieve it.

I first assign individual array item to ViewData and then use ViewData's Eval method.

```
<%
ViewData["SingleNameObject"] = Names[i];
%>

<%=ViewData.Eval("SingleNameObject.FirstName")%>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I fix-it using `ViewData["mylist[0]"] = Model.mylist[0];`

Answer (score 3):

I was looking at this problem when creating custom Html helper methods for rendering controls. I wanted to be able to get the view data model value generically given an expression. The standard ViewData.Eval method works fine for properties, but didn't work at all for more complex cases. I ended up using the DataBinder class as per the example below:

```
var value = DataBinder.Eval(ViewData.Model, "Names[0].FirstName")
```

This seemed to solve my problem.

Comment: greetings from the future, this works great for asp.net and vb.net. did the job good for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
<%=ViewData.Eval("Names.0.FirstName")%>
<%=ViewData.Eval("Names.1.FirstName")%>
```

[ASP.NET MVC ViewData.Eval() method - IBloggable - implemented](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2009/11/26/asp-net-mvc-viewdata-eval-method.aspx)

Comment: The author says it did not work for him. I tried it too and didn't work for me either.